# Invoke startActivityForResult by pressing the button from preferences

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences, android-custom-view, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to implement File Picker in preferences(I could not find it). So, there are Button and TextView. I need to show file dialog, when user click the button. So, I have to invoke startActivityForResult function from my preferences.xml.

Some code:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent){

    LinearLayout layout =  null;

    try {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        layout = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.file_picker_preference, parent, false);

        selectFileButton = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.file_picker_button);
        selectFileButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FilePickerActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);//I CANNOT INVOKE THIS!!!!!
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {          
    }
    return layout;        
}
```

How can I do this? Or if there is some implementation of FilePicker, it will be the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
```

Comment: But how to get `Name_of_prefernces_activity`? Which function should I use?

Comment: @Ares You poseted a code for onCreateView, this method is in which class? And that class extends which class. Like Activity, Preferences??

Comment: It extends Preference class. I used context instead. But there is no `startActivityForResult`, only `startActivity`.